# does dell have a utility to update all drivers and firmware for my server?

Tags: dell

I installed Dell Openmanage Server Administrator, and while it'd show me version numbers of firmware, it wouldn't tell me they were out of date/an update was available.

Does Dell have something that'll do this?

Answer (score 5):

Yes they do. It's called [Server Update Utility](http://www.delltechcenter.com/page/OpenManage+Server+Update+Utility+-+SUU).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Dell Repository Manager](http://www.delltechcenter.com/page/Repository+Manager).

This will bring the firmware packages from Dell on your own machine and build a bootable disk that will take care of all the upgrades.
This will require a reboot of the server and the CD will run smoothly, doing all your upgrades (you don't need to do anything).

A walkthrough can be found here: 
http://lonesysadmin.net/2011/03/07/the-easiest-way-to-update-a-dell-servers-firmware/

Answer (score 2):

Check out this Dell article:

http://www.dell.com/Support/Article/us/en/04/SLN296511

Basically they post a bootable ISO for every server updated up to once a month on more active machines (there is a list of machines there).

URLs look like:
https://dell.box.com/BootableR520

Anyways, these ISOs try to install every single update for a machine.

I would always update the lifecycle, idrac and bios as well as PERC/RAID firmware the old fashioned way, then run something like this. Ive seen a lot of Dell servers brick themselves with bulk updates that involve simultaneous upgrades to BIOS/iDRAC/lifecycle/PERC so do those the normal way or through lifecycle manager.

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned the SUU for 1:1 updates and the IT Assistant for centralised management. There are SUU ISO's available for download for all Dell Servers.

If you have a recent (11G) server - like the R310\410\510\R610\R710 then you also have the option of using the built in [LifeCycle Controller\Unified Server Configurator](http://www.dell.com/content/topics/global.aspx/power/en/simplify_management?c=us&l=en&cs=555). Press F10 at boot and you have a built in version of the SUU plus some more. The USC can be configured to directly synchronize with the Dell ftp site or a controlled staging area and will let you download and patch all of the embedded components (BIOS, controller Firmware, iDRAC and the LifeCycle Controller itself). There have been many improvements to the capabilities in recent updates (roll back of firmware updates, automatic configuration and firmware updates on part replacement for example) so it's a good idea to update the LifeCycle Controller first if there is a new version available.

Answer (score 0):

There's the SUU if you want to update one server, and IT assistant for centralised updating (and monitoring) of many systems.

Answer (score 0):

SUU is still available but it is a huge download, and dell's server is slow.

You can alternately install "Dell Repository Manager", which will let you download the firmware for the particular machines you have, rather than everything in their catalog.